# Proprietary driver utility won't load

Tags: drivers, system-settings, 16.04, glib

I have a xenial with kde5. When I go to proprietary drivers' utility in system settings I see only the flash message about collecting data about my system, but the list of drivers' list never loads. In /var/log/syslog I see:

```
Mar 30 08:09:11 spyzalski dbus[865]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.AptXapianIndex' (using servicehelper)
Mar 30 08:09:11 spyzalski org.debian.AptXapianIndex[865]: Failed to import 'No module named 'glib'', can not use dbus
Mar 30 08:09:11 spyzalski dbus[865]: [system] Activated service 'org.debian.AptXapianIndex' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I believe I have some package missing (this was upgraded directly from 14.04). But what should it be?